# How to determine in Python how many entries in an array are outside a given interval?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a numpy array of size 35x24 and I need to find how many of those values lie outside of a given open interval that is (9.69,11.06). How can I do this?

Comment: ((a<=9.69) | (a>=11.06)).sum()

Answer (score 0):

like Quang mentioned in comments:

```
np.logical_or(array<=9.69, array>=11.06).sum()
```